# Customizing Bootstrap 3.0 Navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0 and I want to customize the navbar links by changing only the **a** tag, and not the whole **li** .

I want to obtain something like this http://templates.designorbital.com/baleen/, but when I change the background color or borders, the whole .li tag gets the same style.

Help?

edit: so far, this is what comes out http://jsfiddle.net/AvxSN/3/

```
/* link */
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #555;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#000;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Please include the html/css you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference I see in the code example you gave and your own is that they have a margin  and border-radius (and different background color on hover) on the `a` element. The `a` in nav are display-block to fill the whole of the `li` element, so that's why when you change something it changes the whole `li`, but it's the same with the example code. Updated yours with a few lines to reflect the example layout. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding you:

http://jsfiddle.net/spacebean/AvxSN/4/

```
/* updated to have same margins as nav items */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #555;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;

}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color:#999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I meant. It seems it's the only way to get that result without changing the whole bootstrap navbar.